# Net core 3 InMemorydatabase problem with JsonDocument parameterless constructor

Tags: asp.net-core, testing, npgsql, in-memory-database, .net-core-3.1

I have .Net Core 3 test project with in memory testing (.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()). My main Database is postgres 12 and

```
[Table("event")]
public class Event
{
    [Column("ev_payload", TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}
```

was replaced by:

```
[Table("event")]
public class Event
{
    [Column("ev_payload")]
    public JsonDocument Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I run my tests. Integration tests and end to end test with postgres are fine but in memory tests fail with an exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Event'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'payload' in 'Event(Guid id, DateTime time, string type, JsonDocument payload)'; cannot bind 'payload' in 'Event(Guid id, DateTime time, string type, JsonDocument payload, DateTime insertedDateTimeUtc, DateTime updatedDateTimeUtc)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConstructorBindingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
   at BpsConsoleTest.TestUtils.Factories.InMemoryDbWebApplicationFactory`1.<ConfigureWebHost>b__2_0(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\tibor.balaz\source\repos\BpsVisualization\BpsConsole\BpsConsoleTest\TestUtils\Factories\InMemoryDbWebApplicationFactory.cs:line 53
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<ConfigureServices>b__0(WebHostBuilderContext _, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder builder, IFeatureCollection featureCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateServer(IWebHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(Uri baseAddress, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient()
   at BpsConsoleTest.BpsConsole.Web.Controllers.UpTimeControllerTest.TestGetUpTime(String url) in C:\Users\tibor.balaz\source\repos\BpsVisualization\BpsConsole\BpsConsoleTest\BpsConsole\Web\Controllers\UpTimeControllerTest.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I presume that it is due to Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL handling JsonDocument and InMemoryTestDatabase trying to use constructor and bind JsonDocument which fails because JsonDocument has internal constructor.

Is there anything that can be done?
Have you ever had the same issue, how did you solve it?

I will be happy for any ideas/help.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems in memory database does not support json column and it can't build a column for type `JsonDocument`. In memory database has a lot of limits.

Comment: True. I was wondering whether someone else had the same issue. Easy solution is to use normal database, but the load and time of testing would exponentially increase. Therefore, I would like to stick with In Memory.

Either way, thank you.

Comment: InMemory definitely isn't meant for arbitrary testing of stuff that normal databases support - it's highly recommended to run tests against your actual database (i.g. PostgreSQL). Note that EF Core itself has a huge number of tests executed against PostgreSQL, and that executes pretty quickly - you have to avoid certain patterns such as recreating databases.

Comment: hi @ShayRojansky, are you suggesting that whenever we use JsonDocument or arrays and we want to unit test stuff we have to run all unit tests against a real database ?

Comment: If you want real unit testing (without a real database), have a repository layer above your DbContext and just mock that. Otherwise, I'd consider just testing against a real database that is the same as your production database (i.e. PostgreSQL) - InMemory simply isn't a good solution.